# React api fetch - wooCommerce & wordpress

Tags: php, reactjs, wordpress, api, woocommerce

I have a site (build with wordpress and woo-commerce).
now Im trying to fetch it into react with no success.
Just trying to show with react the details of the products... (name, price, description)

The code goes like this: `

```
import { Table } from "react-bootstrap";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import moment from "moment";
import "./App.css";
import WooCommerceRestApi from "@woocommerce/woocommerce-rest-api";

const API_URL = new WooCommerceRestApi({
  url: "https://test.local/wp-json/wc/v3/products/",
  consumerKey: "ck_5367a6bdaa476696355c156231b735eb98b46001",
  consumerSecret: "cs_f365c03bf06be03b87bff11e7d17220eb29531f1",
  version: "wc/v3"
});

function App() {
  const [product, setProduct] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchProduct();
  }, []);

  let fetchProduct = () => {
    api
      .get("product", {
        per_page: 20,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          setProduct(response.data);
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {});
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Table striped bordered hover>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Price</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {product.map((liveProduct, index) => {
            return (
              <tr key={index}>
                <td>{liveProduct.id}</td>
                <td>{liveProduct.name}</td>
                <td>{liveProduct.description}</td>
                <td>{liveProduct.price}</td>
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </Table>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I got erros like this..

ERROR in ./src/App.js 9:0-28
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'moment' in '/Users/bida/Desktop/studies/pojects/WEB/react_app/src'

ERROR in ./node_modules/cipher-base/index.js 3:16-43
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/Users/bida/Desktop/studies/pojects/WEB/react_app/node_modules/cipher-base'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
- install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }

ERROR in ./node_modules/hash-base/node_modules/safe-buffer/index.js 4:13-30
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'buffer' in '/Users/bida/Desktop/studies/pojects/WEB/react_app/node_modules/hash-base/node_modules/safe-buffer'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "buffer": require.resolve("buffer/") }'
- install 'buffer'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "buffer": false }

ERROR in ./node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js 46:13-37
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'buffer' in '/Users/bida/Desktop/studies/pojects/WEB/react_app/node_modules/readable-stream/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "buffer": require.resolve("buffer/") }'
- install 'buffer'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "buffer": false }

ERROR in ./node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js 70:13-37
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'buffer' in '/Users/bida/Desktop/studies/pojects/WEB/react_app/node_modules/readable-stream/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "buffer": require.resolve("buffer/") }'
- install 'buffer'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "buffer": false }

ERROR in ./node_modules/readable-stream/lib/internal/streams/buffer_list.js 74:15-32
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'buffer' in '/Users/bida/Desktop/studies/pojects/WEB/react_app/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/internal/streams'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "buffer": require.resolve("buffer/") }'
- install 'buffer'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "buffer": false }

ERROR in ./node_modules/ripemd160/index.js 3:13-37
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'buffer' in '/Users/bida/Desktop/studies/pojects/WEB/react_app/node_modules/ripemd160'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "buffer": require.resolve("buffer/") }'
- install 'buffer'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "buffer": false }

ERROR in ./node_modules/safe-buffer/index.js 2:13-30
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'buffer' in '/Users/bida/Desktop/studies/pojects/WEB/react_app/node_modules/safe-buffer'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "buffer": require.resolve("buffer/") }'
- install 'buffer'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "buffer": false }

ERROR in ./node_modules/string_decoder/node_modules/safe-buffer/index.js 4:13-30
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'buffer' in '/Users/bida/Desktop/studies/pojects/WEB/react_app/node_modules/string_decoder/node_modules/safe-buffer'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "buffer": require.resolve("buffer/") }'
- install 'buffer'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "buffer": false }

ERROR in src/App.js
Line 24:5:  'api' is not defined  no-undef

I really need your help thank you :)

Comment: Sometimes you can solve it by looking at the error message itself. Remove `import WooCommerceRestApi from "@woocommerce/woocommerce-rest-api";` any one of that from your code because it has duplicate.

Comment: yeah i see... but its not the problem...
when i remove one of the duplicated lines it bring me even more errors...

Comment: Your issues not related to WordPress and WooCommerce, I suggest to update your question title more related to React for better visibility for others. While I'm at it, you could try removing `node_modules` folder and `npm install` then rebuild it to see if the error goes away or not.

Comment: I did it... still the same problem